# inserting new line inside of a string literal in react

Tags: reactjs, string, literals

I'm having trouble getting a portion of a string literal to move to a new line. 
I'd like to have the text "Development &" appear on one line and then on the next line the text "Production" would appear. I've tried \n \r and some Unicode combinations, but haven't had any success... any ideas?

```
<Collapsible trigger="Development &amp; Production">
  <SomeOtherComponent />
</Collapsible>
```

Comment: HTML doesn't do "new line": any whitespace gets collapsed. The idea behind HTML is that any visual presentation you need, you achieve using CSS. And while CSS _does_ allow line breaks --through its [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property-- you really shouldn't be using that. If your label needs to be typeset, use proper markup.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that HTML doesn't care about your `\n` and your `\r`. You would need to break this up and use HTML tags that have line breaks.

I'm not sure if the `trigger` prop will also allow you to pass in a ReactElement, if so you would do something like:

`trigger={<><div>Development &amp;</div><div>Production</div></>}`

You can also use `<br />` tags to create line breaks.

Comment: Please, _please_ stop using `<div>` for everything. That's not what `<div>` is for: if you're putting text straight up into a div, you are very much "doing it wrong(tm)". This is heading text, so: _use heading markup_. With a CSS class, because that's the foundation of HTML. And a proper ARIA role.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but misses the point completely. I don't do this myself, but the OP needs to understand block elements and HTML rendering.

Comment: Yes, and you need to teach proper HTML, not just go "the question had bad markup, I better keep that up". SO is here to help people do the right thing, not keep doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Well this conversation is over.

Comment: Not necessarily, because SO exists for a reason: to give people good answers, and that includes correcting bad assumptions they made about what kind of code to write. Your job as person posting answers is not just to go "here is solution bye", you are expected to put in just as much effort as we expect people asking questions to put in. Especially with the problems React has been causing with their waterfalls of `<div>`: don't teach people that `<div>` is fine when it very much isn't. The web has proper markup for a reason, and a good answer teaches good code.

Comment: @Jens thanks your explanation did help me being a beginner.

Comment: @Mike - thanks I guess for trying to help... maybe be a bit nicer to people though?